# Odd behavior with WebUtility.HtmlDecode shows different result from Unit Test vs Deployed Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit.net

My test demonstrates a passing result when deserializing a dynamic to JSON, however when the application is deployed, the deserialization fails with the following error:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)' has some invalid arguments
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
   at Controllers.LockboxController.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<GetVersionedLockboxPaths>b__6(Object desc)
```

The following test successfully deserializes a dynamic (which is a string), by using `HtmlDecode` to convert the encoded JSON into decoded JSON, and hopefully into an Object of Type `Description`.

I am expecting an object returned from the controller as something like:

```
{
    "description": {
        "meta": {
             "date": "2023-03-12T08:59:43.9816969Z",
             "reason": "I am hungry."
        }
    },
    "fullPath": "1234557-0c39-4180-9e58-1234557/.v9/TEST_VERSIONING",
    "lockboxID": "1234557-0c39-4180-9e58-1234557",
    "pathId": 6116019,
    "pathName": ".v9/TEST_VERSIONING",
}
```

The following INFO is logged out, just prior to executing an inline `Func`:

```
GetVersionedLockboxPaths - Description: {&quot;meta&quot;:{&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2023-03-12T17:27:05.6781009Z&quot;,&quot;reason&quot;:&quot;I am hungry.&quot;}}
```

The following Test Harness works as expected.

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test_LockboxController_LockboxPathDescriptionInlineFunc()
    {
        // Arrange
        var regex = new Regex(@"\.v[0-9]*/\w+");
        dynamic description1 = "{&quot;meta&quot;:{&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2023-03-12T17:27:05.6781009Z&quot;,&quot;reason&quot;:&quot;I am hungry.&quot;}}";
        dynamic description2 = "{&quot;meta&quot;:{&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2023-03-12T14:42:41.0964823Z&quot;,&quot;reason&quot;:&quot;Just because.&quot;}}";
        var secretPaths = new List<LockboxPath> {
            new LockboxPath { FullPath = "FOO_PATH", PathId = 1 },
            new LockboxPath { FullPath = ".v0/FOO_PATH", PathId = 1, Description = description1 },
            new LockboxPath { FullPath = ".v1/FOO_PATH", PathId = 2, Description = description2 },
        };
        var secretPathKey = "FOO_PATH";
        var versionedSecretPathKey = ".v1/FOO_PATH";

        // Act
        var versionedSecretPaths = secretPaths
            .Where(s => s.FullPath?.GetMatch(regex) ?? false)
            .Where(s => s.FullPath?.EndsWith(secretPathKey) ?? false)
                .Select(l => {

                    Func<dynamic, dynamic> deserializeDescriptionBody = (desc) => {
                        try
                        {
                            // Actual implementation will log INFO here.
                            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Description>(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(desc));
                        }
                        catch (System.Exception)
                        {
                            // Error described above is logger here
                        }
                        return "";
                    };

                    return new LockboxPath
                    {
                        PathId = l.PathId,
                        PathName = l.PathName,
                        FullPath = l.FullPath,
                        LockboxID = l.LockboxID,
                        Description = deserializeDescriptionBody(l.Description)
                    };
                })
                .OrderByDescending(l => l.PathId)
                .ToList();

        var latestVersionedSecretPath = versionedSecretPaths
            .OrderBy(s => s.PathId)
            .Last();

        // Assert
        Assert.True(versionedSecretPathKey.GetMatch(regex) == true, "Seven Hells!");
        Assert.True(latestVersionedSecretPath.Description?.Meta.Reason == "Just because.", "Seven Hells!");
        Assert.True(latestVersionedSecretPath.Description?.Meta.Reason != "For a very good reason.", "Seven Hells!");

    }
```

Here is the relevant code from my Controller:

```
            versionedLockboxPaths = allLockboxPaths
                .Where(l => (l.FullPath?.GetMatch(new Regex(@"\.v[0-9]*/\w+")) ?? false))
                .Where(l => (l.FullPath?.EndsWith(primaryLockboxPath.PathName ?? throw new NullReferenceException("Seven Hells!")) ?? false))
                .Select(l => {

                    Func<dynamic, dynamic> deserializeDescriptionBody = (desc) => {
                        try
                        {
                            _logger.Information($"GetVersionedLockboxPaths - Description: {desc}");

                            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Description>(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(desc));
                        }
                        catch (System.Exception ex)
                        {
                            _logger.Warning(ex, "Unable to deserialize Description.");
                        }
                        return "";
                    };

                    return new LockboxPath
                    {
                        PathId = l.PathId,
                        PathName = l.PathName,
                        FullPath = l.FullPath,
                        LockboxID = l.LockboxID,
                        Description = deserializeDescriptionBody(l.Description)
                    };
                })
                .OrderByDescending(l => l.PathId)
                .ToList();
```

Can HtmlDecode actually behave differently at runtime, vs. xunit test?  If so, why, and how might this be corrected (also, there is something I might be doing wrong and overlooked).

Comment: `WebUtility.HtmlDecode(desc.ToString())` solves from Controller, but curious why the difference.

Comment: out of curiosity: Why are you defining `description1|2` as dynamic, when they are just plain strings? Will they ever be something else besides a string? If they are just a string, there should be no reason to use dynamic, and if you can submit them as a `description` object, there would be no need to deserialize it in the first place.

Comment: @Marco you have a good point. At first it wasn't clear to me whether the backend would retain a data structure (documentation wasn't clear), so I started out with dynamic thinking I could be saving different structures.  Now I decided to crystalize it into a concrete type.